# How to use CJK font in Mac OS?

Tags: xetex, cjk, xecjk

OS: Mac OS X 10.10

I am trying to write an article in Chinese and English.
The preamble is:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}  % Set main font for ASCII
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=Heiti SC]{Songti SC}
\setCJKsansfont{Heiti SC}
\setCJKmonofont{Courier}
```

I use xelatex to compile the documents with `xelatex article.tex`, then the compiler raised two warnings:

```
fontspec warning: 'script-not-exist'
Font 'Songti SC' does not contain script 'CJK'.
```

and

```
fontspec warning: 'script-not-exist'
Font 'Courier' does not contain script 'CJK'.
```

However, the pdf document was generated and the Chinese words were displayed, except that bold Chinese characters do not work.

I changed the arguments to `Songti` then an error was raised. `Songti SC` and `Heiti SC` are the names I found in "Font Book" in Mac OS. I am confused by the warnings.

How do I set the CJK font correctly?

Comment: here, I met the same issue, though my version is up to 2018 yet, any clue about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a test using Heiti SC (Light and Medium) vs Songti SC (Light and Bold). The results are more visible in the latter.

### Outputs

[image: figure 1]

---

[image: figure 2]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} 
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=Heiti SC Medium]{Heiti SC Light} % \setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=Songti SC Bold]{Songti SC Light}
\setCJKsansfont{Heiti SC}
\setCJKmonofont{Courier}

\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\verb;\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=Heiti SC Medium]{Heiti SC Light};

\Huge   
谢谢

\textbf{谢谢}
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I specify font type by adding `Bold` or `Medium` and it worked. But the warning still occurred.

Comment: @Zelong Which warning?

Comment: the two warnings: `fontspec warning: script-not-exist`

Comment: @Zelong Is your Tex Live up to date?

Comment: Yes, it is the 2014 and no update is available in TexLive Utility.

Comment: @Zelong This is odd. So you're using `xelatex` obviously? What editor are you using? And also, copypasting only my code, nothing else, will still give you the warnings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24676/discussion-between-zelong-and-alenanno).

Comment: I copy your code and the same warnings were raised. I use `xelatex article.tex` in the terminal.

Comment: I use Sublime Text 3. Sorry that I have not enough reputations to discuss in chat network.

Comment: @Zelong Ah ok, why do you compile from the terminal? I don't know if this is the cause, but it may be worth a try!

Comment: @Zelong Try also specifying `Courier New` for the mono font. See if it removes the warning.